# SortBy only works half way in 'inner list'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a RDD which looks like this.

```
[a, ((b, c), d)]
```

I tried sorting by c by the code below

```
sortedMovies = countRatings.sortBy(lambda x : x[1])
```

but it got sorted by b.

```
result: [(1882, ((64.5, 33.0), 1.9545454545454546)), (1499, ((52.0, 27.0), 1.9259259259259258)),(3593, ((31.5, 19.0), 1.6578947368421053)),
```

how can I sort it by c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda is pulling out `((b, c), d)` while you want it to pull out `c`. Therefore:

```
sortedMovies = sorted(countRatings, key=lambda x: x[1][0][1])
```